# Predict temperature (daily or hourly) - which model?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, arima

I have a good dataset of hourly and daily temperature and would like to predict future temperature based on this data with R.

I thought about fitting a time series model to it and use it afterwards for predicting. Any idea which would be suitable? As temperature has saisonality, I guess Holt-Winter would perform well.

ARIMA doesnt include saisonality and thus wouldnt fit the data well. But what about SARIMA? Don't have any profound knowledge about SARIMA though...

If you have any other suggestions besides the ones above, please let me know.

Thank you
Rochus

Comment: With enough years averaging the temperature over many years will give you a very good forecast for the long term. Removing the average will give you a temperature without seasonality which you can forecast with other methods, but this only works very short term. ARIMA usually performs worse than Exponential Smoothings. And the forecast for tomorrow that the temperature will remain the same can outperform ES. Just use test period to see what model performs better. In real life they have a map of cyclones and they predict where the cyclone goes.

Comment: Thank you! 
What I wanted to add, is that I want to predict the future temperature many times in order to get a distribution for every point in time. This premises a stochastic component in the model which is missing in ARIMA as well as HW, right?